# Using GUI programs on a local (Linux) machine from a remote (MacOS) machine using x11?

Tags: linux, ssh, x11, osx

I've spent a bunch of time scanning these (and other) forums for how to remedy the following situation but to no avail. Hopefully someone can share their expertise!

At my University, I'm on a Linux machine (Scientific Linux 7) with `xauth` present:

```
$ which xauth
   /bin/xauth
```

I would like to (a) run GUI apps from my (remote) Macbook (with `XQuartz` present), and (b) have them show up on this Linux machine.

When I run

`ssh -o ForwardX11=yes user@wg-dhcpblahblahblah.secure.wireless.university.edu`

, I'm prompted for my Mac's password; when I enter it, I get my Mac's terminal. When I look around in this terminal, I'm able to access my Mac's files. This part is all well and good.

However, if I attempt to run a Mac (GUI-based) program via the Mac's terminal (as seen on the Linux machine), the GUI opens on the **Mac** and **not** on the Linux machine. For example, running

`/Applications/texstudio.app/Contents/MacOS/./texstudio`

from the Mac's terminal (as seen on the Linux machine) opens TeXStudio's GUI **on the Mac** and **not** on the Linux machine! This, of course, is problematic, as it means that (a) seems to be achieved but (b) has failed.

On the Mac, my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file contains the following lines:

```
   X11Forwarding yes
   X11DisplayOffset 10
   X11UseLocalhost no

# XAuthLocation added by XQuartz (http://xquartz.macosforge.org)
   XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
```

; however, I've also tried it with `X11UseLocalhost yes` to no avail.

Note, too, that x11 seems to be "doing its job," because if I run something like `xeyes` or `xclock` (in the Mac terminal on the Linux machine), I get the eyes/clock showing up (on the Linux machine).

Am I missing something obvious here?

**Notes:**

1. I **can't** make any changes to the Linux machine I'm using: It's
   part of a major-specific Linux computing lab, and no sort of
   installation/"backend file" manipulation can be done.
2. I'm using my university's secure Wi-Fi, both on the Linux machine AND on the Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re missing that macOS GUI applications don’t use X11 and therefore can’t be forwarded to an X11 server using SSH... They use [Quartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_(graphics_layer)) for their display.

As far as I’m aware macOS only supports full-desktop remote display nowadays (except for X11 applications running with XQuartz, as you determined). From one macOS device to another, you can use [Remote Desktop](https://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/); in your case, you’ll need to use something like VNC (run VNC on the Mac, and connect to it with a VNC client).

The Wikipedia [Comparison of remote desktop software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software) has a good overview of the available options: look for software which supports macOS servers and Linux clients.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I'm clearly very ignorant on things like X11, so if you don't mind: Can you elaborate? What do MacOS GUI applications use instead of X11? Since I can't get my desired result using SSH, ARE there alternatives for getting my MacOS GUI applications to run remotely on my Linux machine?